# Calling C++ -> Java with JNI - dependencies

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, dependencies

I try to call java function from c++ using JNI and there is no problem with my own .jar file, but my java part has it's own .jar dependencies. I tried to add it to JavaVM options in c++ as: "-Djava.class.path=a.jar; b.jar", where b.jar is dependency of a.jar but unfortunatly it isn't working. I have always NoSuchMethod exception. Is there something else to add into JavaVM options?

Comment: I use the same option (`-Djava.class.path`), but w/ full path to jars, and everything workd fine. Another one difference: in my arguments to JVM my own JAR is the last (all dependecies are first) -- dunno does it matter... just don't remember...

Comment: OK, I change order of dependencies and now my c++ application doesn't recognize class from my .jar. I always use full paths to jars.

Comment: Maybe way of finding class is incorrect (for just one .jar works, but for two doesn't):
env->FindClass("org/mypackage/myclass");

Comment: OK. Problem solved.
Thank you zaufi. The problem above was with space which shouldn't be added before second .jar path.